# Draw and write text along a spiral with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a spiral with text near the line just like

[image]

I have tried

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,->] (10, 0) -- (-10, 0) node [left] {Review};
\draw [thick,->] (0, -10) -- (0, 10) node [above] {Cumulative costs};
\draw [domain=0:-33, variable=\t, smooth, samples=75, ->] plot ({\t r}: {0.008*\t*\t});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces the annotated axes and a spiral but I don't know how to write text along the spiral.

Comment: When you said "along a spiral", I thought you mean the baseline coincides with the spiral. However in reply to your diagram, lines like `\node at({\t r}: {180+0.008*\t*\t})` would meet your goal.

Comment: By the way, your spiral looks more like **r = √(θ^2+θ)**.

Comment: @Symbol1 Would you answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two possibilities

In the first solution, I create another plot and place nodes on the curve using `decorations.markings` library. The library provides two ways to specify position: either measuring by length or by a factor of total length.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{nodes={font=\ttfamily,fill=white}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,arrows={->[length=10]}](8,0)--(-8,0)node [left] {Review};
    \draw[thick,arrows={->[length=10]}](0,-8)--(0,8)node [above] {Cumulative costs};
    \draw[domain=0:15,variable=\t,samples=440,smooth,arrows={->[length=10]}]
        plot({(-\t+1.5708) r}:{\t/3+2*\t/(0.1+\t)});
    \path[domain=0:15,variable=\t,samples=440,decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position 2cm with \node{2cm};,
                mark=at position .3 with \node{pos=.3};,
            }
        ]
        plot({(-\t-1.5708) r}:{\t/3+2});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Another way is to create a new style which moves nodes to where we want by the parameterization we define.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
            f(\t)=90-\t*90;
            g(\t)=\t/2+2*\t/(0.1+\t);
            f2(\t)=-90-\t*90;
            g2(\t)=\t/2+2;
        },
        pos par/.style={
            shift={({f2(#1)}:{g2(#1)})}
        }
    ]
    \draw[thick,arrows={->[length=10]}](8,0)--(-8,0)node[left]{Review};
    \draw[thick,arrows={->[length=10]}](0,-8)--(0,8)node[above]{Cumulative costs};
    \draw[domain=0:10,variable=\t,smooth,samples=440,arrows={->[length=10]}]
         plot({f(\t)}:{g(\t)});
    \path node[pos par=0]{pos par=0}
          node[pos par=1]{pos par=1}
          node[pos par=2]{pos par=2}
          node[pos par=3]{pos par=3}
          node[pos par=4]{pos par=4}
          node[pos par=5]{pos par=5}
          node[pos par=6]{pos par=6}
          node[pos par=7]{pos par=7}
          node[pos par=8]{pos par=8};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By the way, `\t/(1+\t)` (as well as its linear transformations) is a function that "climbs" to 1 and stays there. I add this function in order to embellish the archimedean spiral so that there would be enough room for the first label.